# How to set element to grow horizontally instead of breaking to a new line?

Tags: javascript

I'm facing problem with breaking the line on website. What do I mean?
HTML code

```
<main class="clearfix">
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
</main>

<button>Add</button>
```

With such HTML code I'd like to have:

- fixed height on main element (for example 80vh)
- fixed height for all the elements first and third 40vh + second 80vh
- fixed width for first and third element 50vw
- fluid width for second element - but this is main problem - second element has to be in the same place and grow horizontally (to create scroll on the bottom of the site)

Please find my [codepen](https://codepen.io/ptr11dev/pen/JqKaay)

I've added button that'll add pixels to second element - but it destroys my website.

I'm not sure if flexbox is better than floats.

I'll appreciate any tip.

Here is the snippet:

```js
let counter = 0;
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".second").style.width = `calc(50% + ${counter}px)`;
  console.log(counter);
  counter++;
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  max-height: 80vh;
}

.first,
.third {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}

.third {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: blue;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<main class="clearfix">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</main>

<button>Add</button>
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve here ? what will the button do on click ? I understood your first requirements, like 1st and 3rd elements will be at the left side, 1st one on the top, 3rd one at the bottom of it, and 2nd one will take up the total height of 1st and 3rd one. then what happens on the click of the button ?

Comment: I'd like to have two block of information on the left side and one block on the right (with visual elements) - user can add elements to the right block - so it has to grow horizontally to show all the elements - I don't want it below or in separate section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with `position` properties. Since you have a little difference between the order of your DOM element and their visual representation, like 1,2,3 in the DOM, but visually it's more like 1,3,2.

However, in such situation `float` is your enemy. I'm not 100% sure about flex, AFAIK flex would keep all the elements inside the parent element and prevent the scrolling.

If you go with `absolute` positioning, *(since you already have the heights and widths defined)*

Apply:

- `position: relative` to the `main` element, it will be the base point of the child elements if they are set to `absolute`.
- `overflow-x: scroll` to the `main` element. it will allow you to scroll horizontally when you increase the width of your second element.
- `position: absolute` on `.first, .second, .third`, as you have the `height` and `width` defined, now set their position accordingly, check the snippet, you'll get it.

Finally you're good to add more value to your width of the target element.

**Tip:** always keep a consistency in your css units, for example, if used `vh` / `vw` use this for similar elements at least, or if `px` / `em` / `rem` is used, try to use the same accordingly.

*Check the snippet in full page mode*

```js
let counter = 0;
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".second").style.width = `calc(50vw + ${counter}vw)`;
  document.querySelector("#added").textContent = counter;
  counter++;
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 80vh;
}

.first,
.third {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.third {
  background-color: red;
  top: 40vh;
}

.second {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 0;
}

button {
  margin: 30px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</main>

<button>Add</button>

<p><span id="added">0</span>vw Added to blue div's width</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally ignored positioning - that's brilliant idea - everything works fine. Once again: thank you!

Comment: @PiotrKaczmarek you're welcome. if you think the answer could help others too, feel free to upvote. thanks